# SSRS The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, oledbconnection

Well, this is a bit awkward.  I currently have a set of reports on a 32-bit sql server 2005 instance that references an access database on a network location.  I'm currently trying to migrate these over to my new reporting services instance (sql server 2008 64-bit), and i've ran into an issue.

[image: Jet Error]

Well, i did a google search on the error and got a bunch of stuff saying to compile to use x86 and use 32-bit, etc., but none of it even touch on if i was getting this in rpeorting services.

My question is, is there a way to "fix" this, or some sort of work-around?  Perhaps there's another provide i can use to get to the access database?
  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the exact same problem today, as you alluded to there is no 64-bit Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider available. This impacts reports that attempt to use Excel and Access datasources on a 64-bit Reporting Services instance. Here is the KB article confirming that no 64-bit Jet driver is available:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957570

The solution I found is from this forum post on MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/9e999fb4-5a39-41c4-8fd7-46193a223673/

It involves creating an SSIS package that reads the Excel or Access data source, running the SSIS package in 32-bit mode, and using the SSIS package as the report datasource. Not ideal, but it works.

I'm afraid this is the nasty workaround to which we're limited.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this, which worked in a specific case:

http://danielcai.blogspot.com/2011/02/solution-run-jet-database-engine-on-64.html

From that post:

Microsoft has released a 64-bit compatible Jet database engine last year. The following is the procedure that you may use to fix this issue:

1. Download Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable (of
   course you'll need to choose the right bit for your server), and
   install it on your server
2. Change your connection string in your code or configuration file from
    Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
    to
    Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;